# How can I display acf metadata array in revolution slider

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, revolution-slider

i'm trying to build a movie slider for a Cinema tv screen.
I started to build custom Fields using acf advanced custom fields in wordpress.

Everything is working except displaying acf metadata with more options. 
The revolution slider and the grid now displays it like the word (array)
[image displaying array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USRhJ.jpg)
this is what I use to display custom fileds in the sliders

```html
**in cornerstone**  
{{acf:field_name}}

**in sidebar**
 [acf field="field_name"]

**in the grid**
#meta:field_name#

**in revolution slider** 
{{meta:field_name}}

**in template**
*// simple*
<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>

*// multiple options*
<?php
 // vars
          $values = get_field('field_name');

          // check
          if( $values ): ?>
              <ul>
                 <?php foreach( $values as $value ): ?>
                   <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
               </ul>
          <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I make this work so it displays more options, like on the [template page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0HxB.png)

Can somebody please help me

Comment: ACF has extensive documentation. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this in revolution slider, so my question is how to do this without php

Comment: WordPres is php and all plugins like ACF are php so you can't output from fields without php. This question makes no sense. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that when using the `{{meta:somemetatag}}` filter with rev slider, it bypasses the acf helper functions, such as `get_field()`, that handle the heavy lifting involved when navigating the various types of objects and arrays when using the more complex ACF fields.  So the trick to getting those values to display properly in your rev slider is to use the native ACF shortcodes in combination with the revslider `{{id}}` filter.

For example, if you're attempting to display the return values from an acf select field in a post based Revolution Slider you could try the following:

`[acf field="my_acf_field_name" post_id="{{id}}"]`

This will output the `my_acf_field_name` ACF field for the current post being rendered by Revolution Slider.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but when I use revsliders {{id}} filter with ACF shortcode it wont work, because it is not taking post id from {{id}}, but when i put ID of custom post manually it works. Am I missing something ?